# discord.py how to give a specific role when adding a reaction to a specific message

Tags: discord.py

after some research I find myself writing here:
I would like that when the user reacts `✅` to a specific message he has to give it a role and take away another role.
But trying it I can't here is the code I used:

```py
spunta = "✅"

#Avvio del Bot
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(749639084267536464)
    global message
    message = message.id(751836025697075270)
    await message.add_reaction(msg, spunta)

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.user == client.user:
        return
    if reaction.message == message and reaction.emoji == spunta:
        role = get(user.guild.roles, id=691004248753832007)
        await client.add_roles(user, role)
```

error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/PC GIUSEPPE/PycharmProjects/LMIIBot Development/LMIIBot Development.py", line 253, in on_ready
    message = message.id(751836025697075270)
NameError: name 'message' is not defined
```

Comment: You are trying to get the `message` object but you have not defined it anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [on_raw_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) which gets passed [RawReactionActionEvent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) as `payload`.

Note: i used the msg id to find the message itself

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)

    # only work if it is the client
    if payload.member.id == client.user.id:
        return

    if payload.message_id == 750089806872314038 and reaction.emoji == '✅':
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='ROLE NAME HERE')
        await payload.member.add_roles(role)
        await reaction.remove(payload.member)
```

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because you didn't define the `message`. You can do this on only a specific channel(I'm not sure maybe it's possible with the guild) with using `fetch_message`. So in the `on_ready` event, you should change `message = message.id()` with `message = channel.fetch_message(id)`. This should work for you.

Comment: it doesn't work, it gives me this [error](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/749639084267536464/751858385443618846/unknown.png) now. [code](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/749639084267536464/751858536463466616/unknown.png)

Comment: Try to delete the `msg` parameter from `await message.add_reaction(msg, spunta)`.

Comment: the result does not change (I also sent the photo of the updated code)

Comment: Are you sure that the message and the channel exist?

Comment: I put the ids back and yes they are, it still gives the same error

Comment: Can you try to change the emoji with the emoji's name-id?

Comment: how do i find out the id of normal emoji?

Comment: I searched it but I couldn't find.